# How to Codesign All ".dylib" files in a bundle?

Tags: xcode, delphi, firemonkey

My app is build by Delphi XE8, in order to submit my app to Mac App store, I need to codesign all dylib files in the app bundle, is there any way to codesign all dylib files at once instead of running "codesign" command one by one?

Comment: You can use the `--deep` parameter or make a shell script.

Comment: Surely you are already scripting your builds?

Comment: If you're not using anything else, check out want-nextgen, my current hobby horse.  https://bitbucket.org/wpostma/wantnext

Comment: @Hans I tried --deep, but it didn't sign the other dylib files..

Comment: So you aren't scripting your build? Time to start.